# Updating series data in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have a graph with dynamic series in it which has to be updated after every 5 minutes through data from an `AJAX` call.

Now i have figured out the `AJAX` call and i am using Highcharts API's to set data in the graphs. But it isn't working properly. The data that is coming from `AJAX` call is correct. But when i set the data in the highchart series, there are certain points missing in the data set on the graph. Plus, its alignment with the y-axis is also not proper.

If anyone could help me out in this, it would be a great help.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/alteclogitec1tikoonikhil/16393b886fe6cedab6318b278303d03f) is the gist for the code

Comment: Please post a live demo of the problem, data returned by AJAX calls (init and dynamic). Have you checked for console errors in your browser Developer Tools?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need run `url` and see what it returns.

Then second, you view source when run page,

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [{{{histKeys}}}]
}
```